# Como detectar a origem(ficheiro) de uma função através da consola de desenvolvedor?

Tags: javascript

Não sei se esta pergunta se encaixa nas normas/escopo do SO, mas aqui vai:

É possível detectar a origem(ficheiro) de uma função javascript através da consola de desenvolvedor nos browser actuais?

Por exemplo:

Tenho um ficheiro javascript com a função:

```
function teste(){
}
```

Entrando no modo de consola se começar a escrever `te` noto que existe uma função `teste`, porém neste momento não sei de onde ela vem.

A meu ver o único método para eu apurar a sua origem seria verificar todas as requisições feitas ao servidor por ficheiros .js e fazer uma pesquisa pela string `teste()` em cada um desses ficheiros.

Porém se o site tiver vários ficheiros javascript fica dificil determinar o ficheiro correcto, isto para não falar se o script não estiver com o código ofuscado o que irá complicar ainda mais as coisas.

O que me leva á pergunta:

**Existe algum método mais viável para eu fazer a deteção da origem desta função?**

Por exemplo se esta função fosse um `event listener` de um clique sobre um botão eu conseguia facilmente detectar a sua origem inspecionado o elemento do botão.

Comment: Você precisa descobrir em que arquivo(ficheiro) a função está declarada?

Comment: Sim exactamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No **chrome**, tem a opção de ir até a definição da função no próprio console.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Já no **firefox** não consegui encontrar uma forma de ir até a declaração da função através do console, porém podemos procurar pelo nome da função em todos os arquivos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]